# Placing bars on x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am looking to have the bars of my graph rest directly on the x-axis while keeping the same ratio between bars and the x-axis. I have written the following code to produce the graph (I can't show the graph due to lack of reputation) If I remove the coord_equal term, then it works and the bars end up on the x-axis and i can adjust the ylim as needed. However, this alters the ratio. Is there a way to get the best of both worlds in this case?

```
plot<-ggplot(SEdatSwim,aes(x=Treatment, y=sqrtswim))+
         geom_bar(stat="identity",width=.5,fill="grey",colour="black",size=.5)+
         geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=sqrtswim-se,ymax=sqrtswim+se),width=.3)+
         geom_line(size=0.5,colour="black")+xlab("Treatment")+ylab("Number of Swims")+
         coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,2.0))+coord_equal(1/0.7)
```